# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre == y -eq en Bash?

Tags: bash, comparaciones, operador

Ya sé que en otros lenguajes a nivel de estructura de datos, la diferencia que hay entre `==` y `equals` es que el primero te compara la direcciones de memoria mientras que el otro te compara 2 objetos.

Me he dado cuenta que en Bash pasa lo siguiente:

```
declare -i varable=0
if test "$(cualquierCosa)" == "0"
        then
        variable=1
    else
       variable=0 
    fi
```

Código 2

```
declare -i varable=0
if test "$(cualquierCosa)" -eq "0"
        then
        variable=1
    else
       variable=0 
    fi
```

En el segundo ejemplo de código nunca entraría al `else`, mientras que en el primero sí entraría. **¿Ambas funcionan con números y caracteres en Bash?**

Comment: Por favor revisa este post : [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449543/shell-equality-operators-eq#:~:text=%3D%3D%20is%20a%20bash%2Dspecific,a%20numeric%20comparison%20of%20course.)

Answer (score 7):

Mientras que `==` (*que por cierto, solo funciona en bash*) solo compara cadenas, la expresión `-eq` solo sirve para datos numéricos.

Para que te hagas una idea, `-eq` sería `==` solo cuando el `-lt` es un `<` valido.

En [Shell equality operators (=, ==, -eq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449543/shell-equality-operators-eq) de Stack Overflow **John Kugelman** dijo:

> It's the other way around: `=` and `==` are for string comparisons, `-eq` is for numeric ones. `-eq` is in the same family as `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, `-ge`, and `-ne`, if that helps you remember which is which.
> `==` is a bash-ism, by the way. It's better to use the POSIX `=`. In bash the two are equivalent, and in plain sh `=` is the only one guaranteed to work.

**Traducción:**

- Funciona así: `=` y `==` se usan para la comparación de cadenas, mientras `-eq` es para la comparación de números.
- `-eq` pertenece a la misma familia que `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, `-ge` y `-ne`, si eso le ayuda a distinguir para que se usa cada uno.
- `==` es un bash-ismo, por cierto. Es mejor usar POSIX `=`. En bash los dos son equivalentes, y en sh el único que se garantiza que funciona es: `=`.

Answer (score 4):

La ayuda de `bash` sobre el *built-in* `test`, indica que los operadores:

- `cadena1 = cadena2` , comparan si las cadenas son iguales
- `cadena1 == cadena2`, es lo mismo a lo anterior, sólo que no viene en la ayuda, sino en [la documentación oficial](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html). Esto hace pensar que es muy propio (pero no necesariamente exclusivo) de Bash en el caso de `test`
- `expr1 -eq expr2`, realizan pruebas aritméticas y sólo se realizarán **en el caso de que ambas expresiones sean enteros positivos o negativos**

Por ejemplo, en el caso de `-eq`, hacer algo de la forma:

```
test "cadena" -eq 0
```

Resultaría en el error *bash: test: cadena: integer expression expected*

En tú segundo código si se podría entrar al bloque `else`; siempre y cuando lo que se evalue sea una cadena que parezca entero y sea diferente de cero.